# How to send AT command to sim800l with SoftwareSerial

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-nano, gsm, softwareserial

I have SIM800l module connected to Arduino and I'm trying to initialize it in my setup function with this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//SIM800 TX is connected to Arduino D8
#define SIM800_TX_PIN 6
//SIM800 RX is connected to Arduino D7
#define SIM800_RX_PIN 7
SoftwareSerial serialSIM800(SIM800_TX_PIN,SIM800_RX_PIN);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(38400);
  while(!Serial);
  serialSIM800.begin(38400);
  Serial.println("wait for .... it");
  delay(10000);


  // comments added just for example, both commands return junk
  //serialSIM800.write("AT\r\n"); 
  //serialSIM800.write("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"Contype\",\"GPRS\"\r\n");

  Serial.println("command sent");
  delay(2500);

  Serial.write(serialSIM800.read());
}
```

But `Serial.write` returns junk.

When I use this code in loop:

```
  //Read SIM800 output (if available) and print it in Arduino IDE Serial Monitor
  if(serialSIM800.available()){
    Serial.write(serialSIM800.read());
  }
  //Read Arduino IDE Serial Monitor inputs (if available) and send them to SIM800
  if(Serial.available()){    
    serialSIM800.write(Serial.read());
  }
```

and send `AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"` or just `AT` command with serial monitor, everything works fine.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Can you place your schematic? Are you using the 4V regulation and transistor on RST pin? Maybe [this library](https://cristiansteib.github.io/Sim800l/) might help

Comment: What sort of junk? Copy and paste please. Also writing the output from a read, without testing for `available` is likely to return "junk" or at least `ÿ`.

Comment: You're reading only a byte like others have noted. Also, you seem to be sending 2 commands, one immediately after the other. This could result in gibberish. Though it would be nice to see exactly what your 'junk' results are.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised you have put a bounty of +100 rep on this question, but are not answering queries like the comments above, that might help resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use serialSIM800.println("AT") instead of write. Here some examples https://github.com/stanleyhuangyc/Freematics/issues/17

Answer (score 1):

[NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial) would be better for this.  It can read and write at the same time, unlike SoftwareSerial, and it doesn't disable interrupts for the entire character receive time (~1ms!).  AltSoftSerial would be even better, but you can only use it on pins 8 & 9 (on an UNO, different pins on other Arduinos).

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you said that ...but Serial.write return's junk....
Make sure that serial print is Both NL & CR

Answer (score 1):

You are getting junk because of baud rate, set as 9600.

Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  serialSIM800.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("wait for .... it");
  delay(10000);

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, SIM800 modems are very 1990s, they default to 9600 baud. You will get garbage at 38400.

I successfully used a SIM800 at 9600.

Answer (score 0):

My SIM808 returns a bit of junk right from the get-go, so that might be influencing things.

Also, it's conceivable you are retrieving a -1 from your initial serialSIM800.read() call - it's a nonblocking call and returns -1 when no data is available.  That would almost definitely appear as junk.

Answer (score 0):

Sim800 series free Atcommander software.

http://bayanbox.ir/info/3493267131357723232/ATcenter